# FirebaseAnalytics "First open" not displaying In-App Message

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, firebase-in-app-messaging

FirebaseAnalytics In-App message targetting "First open" (image below) never shows the In-App message with either `firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, Bundle())` or `firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, null)` being called from my application's Application#onCreate().

Other events in my app, like `firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("first_contact_added", null)`, display the appropriate In-App message.

Currently using `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'`

[image]

Comment: Hey @Bill Mote, did you solved your problem or figured out the reasons for that? I'm currently experience the same problem that no In-App Message is displayed when using "First Open" as target.

Comment: Nope. I've found no fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the in-app message dialog to only show up when the user has installed and ran your app for the very first time? if so then you don't need to log APP_OPEN just add on_foreground and app_launch on the campaign trigger.

Comment: I will give that a try.

Comment: FYI, made no difference.